# Using an instance in all functions

Tags: c#, instance

For testing purposes I wanted to create a little console game. The game is about having some pandas which need to be fed.

So I wanted to write some functions for every situation like "Overview" or "Shop". For the Pandas I use a class "Panda". But when I use `Panda p1 = new Panda()` in the first function I can't use it in other functions.

How can I write a function that creates some instances of a class which are available in all functions?

The whole thing should be like this:

```
namespace PandaWorld
{
    public class Panda
    {
        ...
    }

    class Game
    {
        void CreatePanda()
        {
            ...    //like Panda p1 = new panda();
        }
        static void Main()
        {
            ...  //uses p1 and other pandas
        }
    }
}
```

I could use a static Panda but I want to be able to "create" more Pandas in runtime.

Answer (score 0):

Make the Panda class a singleton class.

For more instructions 
http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ff650316.aspx

Comment: I guess I read the question wrong. Sorry for the misleading answer

Answer (score 0):

You could write a static wrapperclass for your pandas, which keeps a static list of panda objects and access them like;

```
PandaStaticWrapper.GetPanda(pandaName);
```

create a new

```
PandaStaticWrapper.CreateNewPanda(pandaName);
```

Answer (score 0):

if i understood the question right...
it is not about creating the instance differently, it is to pass references to that instance...

e.g.

```
class MyClassA {
     Panda myClassPanda;

     void func1() 
     { 
          // assign a new panda to a shared reference...
          myClassPanda = new Panda(); 
          myClassPanda.Name = "Kung Fu";
     }

     void func2()
     {
         Console.WriteLine("the panda name is {0}", myClassPanda.Name);
     }

}
```

Also you can create a static reference dictionary of living pandas like so:

```
public class Panda
{
    private static Dictionary<string, Panda> LivingPandaz = new Dictionary<string, Panda>();

    public static Panda GetPanda(string pandaName)
    {
        Panda thePanda;
        if (!LivingPandaz.TryGetValue(pandaName, out thePanda)) {
            thePanda = new Panda(pandaName);
            LivingPandaz.Add(pandaName, thePanda);
        }
        return thePanda;
    }

    private Panda(string pandaName)
    {

    }        
}
```

Maybe add a Disposable, and Kill the living panda when it is not needed anymore.
and so you can get reference to all the living pandas from anywhere...

Cheers.

Answer (score 0):

If you use your Pandas in function of Class `Game` then create a private member for Pandas

Because you need few pandas then use `List` or `Dictionary`

```
Class Game
{
    private List<Panda> allPandas;

    void Main()
    {
        this.allPandas = new List<Panda>();
        this.allPandas.Add(new Panda()); //first panda
        this.allPandas.Add(new Panda()); //second panda

    }

    void AnotherFunction()
    {
        //here you can use functions of your first panda by index
        this.allPandas[0].PandasFunction()
    }
}
```

[About List](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/6sh2ey19.aspx)

On my opinion better if you can give some custom `key` for separated pandas. Then use a `Dictionary`:

```
private Dictionary<String, Panda> allPandas;
```

in Main()

```
this.allPandas = new Dictionary<String,Panda>();
this.allPandas.Add("PandaName", new Panda());
```

in other functions:

```
this.allPandas["PandaName"].PandasFunction();
```

[About Dictionary](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/xfhwa508.aspx?cs-save-lang=1&cs-lang=csharp#code-snippet-1)

If your game have more classes that one which need using a instances of `Panda`, then maybe better practice will be refer a instance of `Panda` to them through `Constructor` or straight to function as parameters.

```
AnotherGameClass
{
    private Panda _handlePanda;

    public AnotherGAmeClass(Panda handledPanda)
    {
        this._handlePanda = handledPanda
    }

    //or straight to function
    public void CheckPanda(Panda checkingPanda)
    {
        //use your panda here
    }

}
```